# The queryset's `count` is wrong after `extra`

Tags: django

When I use `extra` in a certain way on a Django queryset (call it `qs`), the result of `qs.count()` is different than `len(qs.all())`.  To reproduce:

Make an empty Django project and app, then add a trivial model:

```
class Baz(models.Model):
    pass
```

Now make a few objects:

```
>>> Baz(id=1).save()
>>> Baz(id=2).save()
>>> Baz(id=3).save()
>>> Baz(id=4).save()
```

Using the `extra` method to select only some of them produces the expected count:

```
>>> Baz.objects.extra(where=['id > 2']).count()
2
>>> Baz.objects.extra(where=['-id < -2']).count()
2
```

But add a `select` clause to the `extra` and refer to it in the `where` clause, and the count is suddenly wrong, even though the result of `all()` is correct:

```
>>> Baz.objects.extra(select={'negid': '0 - id'}, where=['"negid" < -2']).all()
[<Baz: Baz object>, <Baz: Baz object>]   # As expected
>>> Baz.objects.extra(select={'negid': '0 - id'}, where=['"negid" < -2']).count()
0   # Should be 2
```

I think the problem has to do with `django.db.models.sql.query.BaseQuery.get_count()`.  It checks whether the BaseQuery's `select` or `aggregate_select` attributes have been set; if so, it uses a subquery.  But `django.db.models.sql.query.BaseQuery.add_extra` adds only to the BaseQuery's `extra` attribute, not `select` or `aggregate_select`.

How can I fix the problem?  I know I could just use `len(qs.all())`, but it would be nice to be able to pass the `extra`'ed queryset to other parts of the code, and those parts may call `count()` without knowing that it's broken.

Comment: Verified that the problem is still present in Django 1.2.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redefining `get_count()` and monkeypatching appears to fix the problem:

```
def get_count(self):
    """
    Performs a COUNT() query using the current filter constraints.
    """
    obj = self.clone()
    if len(self.select) > 1 or self.aggregate_select or self.extra:
        # If a select clause exists, then the query has already started to
        # specify the columns that are to be returned.
        # In this case, we need to use a subquery to evaluate the count.
        from django.db.models.sql.subqueries import AggregateQuery
        subquery = obj
        subquery.clear_ordering(True)
        subquery.clear_limits()

        obj = AggregateQuery(obj.model, obj.connection)
        obj.add_subquery(subquery)

    obj.add_count_column()
    number = obj.get_aggregation()[None]

    # Apply offset and limit constraints manually, since using LIMIT/OFFSET
    # in SQL (in variants that provide them) doesn't change the COUNT
    # output.
    number = max(0, number - self.low_mark)
    if self.high_mark is not None:
        number = min(number, self.high_mark - self.low_mark)

    return number

django.db.models.sql.query.BaseQuery.get_count = quuux.get_count
```

Testing:

```
>>> Baz.objects.extra(select={'negid': '0 - id'}, where=['"negid" < -2']).count()
2
```

Updated to work with Django 1.2.1:

```
def basequery_get_count(self, using):
    """
    Performs a COUNT() query using the current filter constraints.
    """
    obj = self.clone()
    if len(self.select) > 1 or self.aggregate_select or self.extra:
        # If a select clause exists, then the query has already started to
        # specify the columns that are to be returned.
        # In this case, we need to use a subquery to evaluate the count.
        from django.db.models.sql.subqueries import AggregateQuery
        subquery = obj
        subquery.clear_ordering(True)
        subquery.clear_limits()

        obj = AggregateQuery(obj.model)
        obj.add_subquery(subquery, using=using)

    obj.add_count_column()
    number = obj.get_aggregation(using=using)[None]

    # Apply offset and limit constraints manually, since using LIMIT/OFFSET
    # in SQL (in variants that provide them) doesn't change the COUNT
    # output.
    number = max(0, number - self.low_mark)
    if self.high_mark is not None:
        number = min(number, self.high_mark - self.low_mark)

    return number
models.sql.query.Query.get_count = basequery_get_count
```

I'm not sure if this fix will have other unintended consequences, however.